# unix command to copy all .h file with modified directory-structure

Tags: bash, shell, bsd

Suppose I have a folder structure like:

Libraries\

- UIToolkit\

  - files\

    - toolkit.h
    - toolkit.c
    - toolkit.resource
- NetworkLayer\

  - files\

    - network.h
    - network-info.txt

...

I need a command so that I can input the Libraries folder and specify a Output folder then in the Output folder I have:

Output\

- UIToolkit\

  - toolkit.h
- NetworkLayer\

  - network.h

Basically it:

1. copies all .h file and preserves the folder structure
2. also move all the headers to its sub-libraries' root folders no matter how deep they are in the sub-libraries sub-folders.

I was using rsync but it does not do 2nd step, so I guess I need some quick and dirty modification?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

```
cd /path/to/Libraries
while read -r file; do
  odir=$(cut -d'/' -f2 <<< ${file});
  fname=$(basename ${file});
  cp "$file" "/path/to/Output/${odir}/${fname}";
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.h")
```

This would copy all the `*.h` files to the `Output` folder as per the desired directory structure.

Comment: Hi how many < are there after `done`? I tried with 3 and the result of `find` is just one line with all file names, how can I line break them?

Comment: @hzxu I believe that there was an extra closing parenthesis that might have been causing the issue.  Check the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

A bit modified answer based on devnull's:

```
idir=$1
odir=$2

while read -r f; do
    subdir=${f#$idir}
    subdir=${subdir%%/*}
    mkdir -p $odir/$subdir
    cp -a $f $odir/$subdir
done < <(find $idir -type f -name "*.h")
```

call something like

```
./thisscript.sh Libraries Output
```

shall be able to work with absolute or relative directories, IMHO; but won't handle if .h file is right under Libraries (must be at least one subdir level down..).